# How do I fetch data in excel from a weblink by (Data>from web) method for 1000 stocks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to fetch same data for all 1000 stocks but cant do the same procedure individually 1000 times then how to do it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Web scraping...? try - [Python](https://www.python.org/), [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib)